# C# regular expression match pattern with indentation

Tags: c#

I have a text file, and i want to match 3 lines that occur 10 times within the text file. My problem is to match those 3 lines with indentation, and the third line can be any words

Line example:

```
    Then something something 

        Follow by something found 

        Something something
```

This is what i have tried so far:

```
string pattern = @"\s\s\s\sThen([\s\S]*)found(\n|\r|\r\n)(\s\s\s\s\s\s)(.*)";
match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

The result gives me 500 matches, which is not what im looking for.

Comment: Please provide more information.Provide exact input text and result

Comment: Why -1? I dont jnow how i could be more clear, thats the input and result

Comment: So the word "Then" should be in the first line, "Follow" in second, "Something" in third? Should they be capitalized or does not matter? Also, in the example the indentation for 1st line is different then for the other two. Is that intentional?

Comment: They are capitalized, and yes the indentations are intentional

Comment: There are a number of questionable aspects of your regex.  `[\s\S]` is any space or non-space character.  Which is just all characters or `.`.  And `\s\s\s\s` is better expressed as `\s{4}`

Comment: You can also look at my pattern, the first line has 4 spaces, the sencind and third have six spaces

Answer (score 0):

I'm making wild guesses about the required format, but you can try something like this:

```
var text = @"    Then something something
      Follow by something found
      Something something
      ";
var pattern = @"[ ]{4}Then[\w\s]+(\r|\n|\r\n)[ ]{6}[\w\s]+found(\r|\n|\r\n)[ ]{6}[\w\s]+(\r|\n|\r\n)";
var match = Regex.Match(text, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: Well it matches the sample string. You can try commenting out some parts  of the regex and see what exactly fails to match.

Comment: It worked. I didn't copy it right from the first place. Thanks